# findAll() in BeautifulSoup missing nodes

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, findall

The method **findAll()** in BeautifulSoup does not return all elements in XML. If you look the code below and open URL, you can see that there are 10 *PubmedArticle* nodes in XML. However the findAll method only finds 6 of them. There is only 6 * on the output instead of 10. What am I doing wrong?

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=pubmed&rettype=abstract&id=23858559,23858558,23858557,23858521,23858508,23858506,23858494,23858473,23858461,23858404'
data = urllib2.urlopen(URL).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

for x in soup.findAll('pubmedarticle'):
    print '*'
```

Comment: Your code works for me and prints 10 `*` chars.

Comment: Try to use `lxml` parser with beautifulsoup: `soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")` (make sure `lxml` is installed).

Comment: In that case, why not use lxml directly ? ^^ (joke aside, it has an awesome xpath support).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding `xml` argument. Make sure you have `lxml` installed.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(xmlData, 'xml')
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I've discovered that 'findAll' is relative to the current node, you can set the root node with soup.

The entities in the provided xml are named "PubMedArticle", so try with the following:

```
for x in soup.pubmedarticleset.findAll('pubmedarticle'):
    print '*'
```

Comment: Yes, I knew that. But if I do so, I get no * whatsoever. So I used lower capitals on purpose.